# SQLAlchemy Query Possible?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

This code doesn't work.  Is there a way to make something like this happen in SQLAlchemy?  In the below there is a table named "Game_Table" and it has a column called "name".

```
list_of_games = session.query(Game_Table).all()
list_of_games.filter(name=="stuff").all()
```

EDIT: The purpose of this code is that I need to do the same query, and then manipulate the results, many times.  So to optimize the code I want to do the query at the beginning and get the results once, and then do different manipulations on the same results each time.

Comment: use `filter_by(name="stuff")` or `filter(Game_Table.name=="stuff")`

Comment: Paulo, you are missing the point of the question.  I want to get a list of entries and then store it.  Then with that saved list of entries, continue to do sqlalchemy type operations on it.

Comment: store it without the `.all()` (this method will turn it into a list, preventing you from method-chaining later)

Comment: without the .all() it is just a query, it doesn't actually gather the items.  the point is that i want to query a DB and get a list of games, and then manipulate that list many times.  so i want to query and build the list just once to save time.

Comment: I think you should use a more descriptive title, no-one will really find this question via Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything before the `.all` is reusable, but `.all` will trigger evaluation and set the result into stone. My advice is never store the `.all` if you intend to reuse the query, use it only when you need the data (this is the whole point of lazy evaluation, only fetch the data when you really need it).

Instead of:

```
list_of_games = session.query(Game_Table).all()
list_of_games.filter(name=="stuff").all()
```

Use:

```
list_of_games = session.query(Game_Table)
list_of_games.all()
list_of_games.filter(name=="stuff").all()
```

[update]

> So it sounds like there is no way to do what I want to do? – appleLover

AFAIK you can only method-chain queries, not results. And it makes sense: why pay a round-trip to the database if the result is already in memory? Filtering/ordering it in pure Python will be less expensive.

```
# old school lisper style.
sorted(list_of_games, key=lambda x: x.name)
filter(lambda x: x.name=='stuff', list_of_games)
# new style
[x for x in list_of_games if x.name=='stuff']
```

If you are just iterating over the result, make it a generator expression -
should be away less expensive than hitting the database again even for large 
results.

```
for game in (x for x in list_of_games if x.name=='stuff'):
    print_score(game)
```

Comment: So it sounds like there is no way to do what I want to do?

Comment: okay thanks for the answer.  sorry if i was unclear in the original question.  i will accept your answer in a day or two if no one else comes up with a solution.

Comment: See my update, don't it make sense to filter in Python if you have the result in memory already?

Comment: Paul, that is what I am doing now.  However I would still like to do it through SQLAlchemy because it is a more intuitive way for me to structure these programs I am making.

Answer (score 0):

`session.query(Game_Table).all()` returns a list.
therefore, you cannot filter it further using alchemy's filter method.

`filtered_list_of_games = [g for g in list_of_games if g.name=="stuff"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your list using python or the sqlalchemy filter. But you cannot use an sqlalchemy `filter()` on a python list returned by `all()`.

You can filter your list exclusively in python (1), exculsively using a sqlalchemy filter (2),
or a mix of them (3).

(1) Manipulate (filter) data in python:

```
games = session.query(Game_Table).all() #returns a list
star_games = [g for g in games if g.name.upper().startswith('star')]
old_games = [g for g in games if g.year < 1999]
```

(2) Make multiple query on your database (being queried is its purpose by the way):

```
games = session.query(Game_Table) #returns a sqlalchemy query instance
star_games = games.filter(Game_Table.name.like('star%').all()
old_games = games.filter(Game_Table.date < 1999).all()
```

In both cases, star_games and old_games contain the same list, the first is filtered using python and the latter is filtered by your database engine.

(3) You can also filter your list using sqlalchemy first, then filter results using python:

```
games = session.query(Game_Table).filter(Game_Table.date < 1999) #returns a python list
old_star_games = [g for g in games if g.name.upper().startswith('star')]
old_noname = [g for g in games if not g.name]
```

--

Additionally, note that sqlalchemy is designed for **filter reuse**, rather than to limit the number of queries on the database (which is meant to be queried). Example of doing the same as above with query reuse:

```
games = session.query(Game_Table) #returns a sqlalchemy query instance
old_games = games.filter(Game_Table.date < 1999) #also returns a sqla query instance,
                                                 #which you can reuse (see below)
old_star_games = old_games.filter(Game_Table.name.like('star%').all()
old_noname = old_games.filter(Game_Table.name == None).all()
star_games = games.filter(Game_Table.name.like('star%').all() #this one does not filter on date
```